# Internal Server Error returned when accessing aws Serverless API deployed to AWS API gateway

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I'm trying to deploy an API that manipulates the AWS DynamoDB database. I used the serverless API template provided by the AWS .Net SDK. The .Net Core API works fine locally, but will return an "Internal server error" whenever I try to access the API after I published it to AWS Lambda.

In the CloudWatch Logs Insights, the log message returns something like this

> An exception was thrown when the constructor for type
>   'ProjectAPI.Controllers.MyController' was invoked. Check inner exception for more details.: LambdaException
>
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
>
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)

In the constructor of MyController I instantiate a service and that service will fetch credentials and setup the DynamoDBContext.

In MyController:

```
private readonly IMyService _myService;
public CoffeeController(IMyService myService){ 
     _myService = myService;
}
```

In MyService: IMyService

```
private readonly DynamoDBContext _context;

public CoffeeService()
{
      var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
      AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
      if (chain.TryGetAWSCredentials("Hackathon-coffee", out awsCredentials)){
            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
            _context = new DynamoDBContext(client, new DynamoDBContextConfig { ConsistentRead = true, SkipVersionCheck = true });

      }else
            LambdaLogger.Log("Cannot Fetch Credentials");
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
  services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
}
```

I presume there is something wrong when fetching the credentials, but i'm not sure how to do it appropriately in .Net Core environment.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `"Hackathon-coffee"` is referring to a credentials profile stored on your local development environment. That profile won't exist in the Lambda environment.

In Lambda you most likely want to use the credentials for the IAM Role that is assigned to the Lambda function when you created it.

Basically when running in Lambda you want to construct your `AmazonDynamoDBClient` without passing in a `AWSCredentials`. The SDK will automatically resolve the credentials for the assigned role. This is also true for region parameter in the constructor. If you construct an `AmazonDynamoDBClient` with the empty constructor it will configure the client with credentials for the IAM role and the region the function is running in.

A handy trick I use in my code sometimes to figure out if I'm running in Lambda is check to see if the `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` environment variable is set.

```cs
private readonly DynamoDBContext _context;

public CoffeeService()
{
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT")))
      {
         var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
         AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
         if (chain.TryGetAWSCredentials("Hackathon-coffee", out awsCredentials))
         {
            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
            _context = new DynamoDBContext(client, new DynamoDBContextConfig { ConsistentRead = true, SkipVersionCheck = true });

         }
         else
         {
            LambdaLogger.Log("Cannot Fetch Credentials");
         }
      }
      else
      {
         // Use credentials from IAM Role and region the function is running in.
         AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
         _context = new DynamoDBContext(client, new DynamoDBContextConfig { ConsistentRead = true, SkipVersionCheck = true });
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have tried your logic to test the serverless application. However, it still returns **internal server error**.  I tried to use LambdaLogger to see what's going on, but it seems LambdaLogger does not work with serverless application, as none of the logs has shown up in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: I also tried running the api locally using `sam local start-api --profile myprofile`, which returns **internal server error**. In the terminal, I got these logs: Unhandled exception occured in runner:
AWSLambda.Internal.Bootstrap.LambdaValidationException: Could not find the specified handler assembly with the file name '<ProjectName>, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The assembly should be located in the root of your uploaded .zip file.

Comment: With the error message "Could not find the specified handler assembly ..." that implies the Handler property In the serverless.template file is incorrect. The value for the property should be <assembly-name>::<full-type-name>::<method-name>.

Comment: I have changed my project's name manually previously and the serverless.template is automatically generated by using the serverless API template. Normally, would you need to change the handler in order to make your API work?